# Python Selenium Webdriver - Try except loop

Tags: python, selenium, try-except

I'm trying to automate processes on a webpage that loads frame by frame. I'm trying to set up a `try-except` loop which executes only after an element is confirmed present. This is the code I've set up:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    try:
        link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(linkAddress)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(2)
```

The above code does not work, while the following naive approach does:

```
time.sleep(2)
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(linkAddress)
```

Is there anything missing in the above try-except loop? I've tried various combinations, including using time.sleep() before `try` rather than after `except`.

Thanks

Comment: Your current code only sleeps if the element is not found.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that it waits 2 seconds before trying again, unless there's something wrong in the implementation?

Comment: I think I was confused by the wording of "executes after an element is confirmed present". My previous comment was an error.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception that you would expect it to throw is occurring in the `try` block?

Comment: Yes. However, I've also tried `except` without explicitly referencing the exception. Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer on your specific question is:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

link = None
while not link:
    try:
        link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(linkAddress)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(2)
```

However, there is a better way to wait until element appears on a page: [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: This works perfectly...Thanks very much! Seems like the error had to do with the logic behind the iteration.

Answer (score 8):

Another way could be.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, linkAddress))
    )
except TimeoutException as ex:
            print ex.message
```

Inside the WebDriverWait call, put the driver variable and seconds to wait.

Comment: This does not work for me. Error message: `NameError: global name 'TimeoutException' is not defined`. I think for this example to work you'd at least need to `import selenium` and then replace line 5 by `except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException as ex:`.

Comment: yes, you need. from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException