# Python selenium is_displayed method

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to be able to reach the else statement and not get an exceptions when the element is not displayed.

for example:

```
 if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/article[2]/div[4]/header/div[2]/div/div[3]/a[4]").is_displayed():
            print("yeah found it")
        else:
            print("not found")
```

Comment: i want to get to the else statement however when the element is not displayed then i will get an exception instead of print("not found")

Comment: i know there is no such element thats why i want it to print not found or in other case i want it to continue with the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CANNOT call is_displayed() or any other property on an element that **does not exist**. is_displayed() only would work if the element present in the DOM but hidden or displayed. your program is failing before even reaching the code to check if it is displayed or not. So the possible fix is probably to use some kind of try catch instead

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

found = False
while not found:
    try:
        link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(linkAddress)
        found = True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(2)
```

Example code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741591/python-selenium-webdriver-try-except-loop)

Comment: This is not what am looking for, am looking for a way i can keep running the test without getting an exception even though the element i was looking for is not found. So if element is not found jump to the else statment and see whats in there to run

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you correctly. How would you keep running a test if the intended element is not found?

Comment: never mind your answer was great i tweaked your code alittle bit and now its working fine thank u very much.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and this Q&A block was the game changer. I tweaked the given code by [Saifur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821981/saifur) too, to match my needs, which I believe similar to this question's request:

```
elementlist = []
found = False
while not found:
    try:
        element_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='class' and (contains(text(),'Optional-text-contain'))]")
        if element_.is_displayed():
            value = element_.find_element_by_css_selector("*")
            elementlist.append(value.text)
            print("Element: " + value.text)
            found = True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        elementlist.append("N/A")
        print("Element: N/A")
        found = True
```

This code looks for an alternating element within the page (sometimes exists, sometimes doesn't). If it exists, it gives its' value. If not - it continues normally while appending the list a "NaN" style value, just to match axis for later DFing

Again, [Saifur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821981/saifur) delivered enormous assistance in this issue. Thank you [user3691239](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3671239/user3671239) for asking this question, and mentioning it worked for you after a lil' tweak.